# angularjs starting point where how sequence

Tags: angularjs, where-clause

I'm a seasoned .ASPX developer w/ lots of JavaScript, and some jQuery done too. Even new to AngularJS, I spent quite some time reading and did hands-on tutorial, easy.

But, after tutorial and simple project, I always got stuck because don't know where is the **starting point** of Angular execution, partly confused by so many .js files and the coding style of in-line/chainable function construction.

Web Form backend usually starts from Page_Load() of .cs file.

Client-side jQuery and JavaScript I can look for 
 - $.ready()
 - straight statements such var x=... outside of any function
   definitions.

Perhaps, I should look for **ng-app** and all **ng-controller** directives inside of the first index.html. Well, what if there are many .js files?

I thought of setting up some break points using client-side debugger. Again, there is no line to set if I don't know this module will be visited.

I appreciate if someone can give me a guideline on how to follow the execution, HOW to find the WHERE. This is one of the [sample project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-with-Web-API-43e5de16) I got confused

I'm sorry if this question is too broad.

Answer (score 3):

By default angularjs app is automatically bootstrapped by looking for ng-app  or ng-controller attributes in html tags. This is way js files of an angularjs app is usually put at the end of the html file. Otherwise, the javascript will be executed before your html finished loading and usually you will get an error message printed in console output.

You can also manually bootstrap an angular app using the document ready event. Have a look at:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

In my project, I have used manual bootstrap to run the angular app only when all files are loaded. I defined a main function and run this function on document loaded event.

```
            /// <summary>
            /// Bootstrap the ng-app on DOM loaded.
            /// </summary>
            $().ready(function () {
                main();
            });
```

In side the main function, I initialized the angular app, e.g. load modules, register services/controllers, setup routes.

```
            /// <summary>
            /// Entry point of the application.
            /// </summary>
            function main() {

                ngModule = angular.module("YourApplication", ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.select', 'ui.slider', 'ngCookies']);

                // register services
                ngModule.service('AppManager', Services.AppManager);

                // register controllers
                 ngModule.controller("LoginController",Controllers.LoginController);

                ngModule.config(angularConfigure);

                // This line cause the angular app to bootstrap
                angular.bootstrap('body', ['YourApplication']);
            }
```

I find a good collection of resources on learning AngularJs and believe it will be helpful.

https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning

Comment: Yang, thanks for the direction.
Attributes ng-app and ng-controller are what I have figured. However, there are some sample don't have ng-controller, for instance [basic links](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-with-Web-API-43e5de16).
The Bootstrap link at AngularJS official site mentioned "Deferred Bootstrap" by using NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP! so Batarang and alikes can hook into the process. But it's poorly documented. 
Wondering if you can share some HOW.

Comment: @Jeb50 Please check my updated answer, hope it can help.

Comment: @Jeb50 This link explains how ng-controller works. http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Comment: Arthur, looks great, thanks for helping. Making progress now.

Answer (score 0):

The sample project you mentioned has a file named app.js. Thats the place where all the routes are configured. That is the config which tells angular which controller js to invoke depending upon the url entered in the browser. For e.g.,  /simplePaging the controller is simpleCtrl which can be found in simpleCtrl.js. Just follow the routes in app.js and you should be able to understand the code.

Comment: The funny part is it has **no ng-controller**.